# How to make user search show results dynamically under the bar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I make my search bar similar to facebook in that It dynamically renders users. I want to show the 5 most relevant users right under the search bar while typing each character.

Currently I have a working search in my header as follows:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', :class => "navbar-search" do %>
  <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Find People", :class => "search-query", id: "headersearch" %>
  <div class="icon-search"></div>
<% end %>
```

It goes to a different page using my users controller #index method:

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page]).search(params[:search])
end
```

In index view:

```
<%= render @users %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised) free Railscast. If you subscribe to them there's an updated pro one too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something similar to [this??](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)